# When does java MongoClient establish a connection to the DB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working with the java Mongo driver 3.2 and I'm trying to figure out exactly what I should have multiple instances of and what should be persisted across the app.

So, for example, `MongoClient` says that there should be only one instance for the app.  It also says that it establishes a connection pool.  Which is great.   When are those connections actually made?  I want to make sure I'm effectively using the pool.

So is the connection to the DB made when I do `MongoClient#getDataBase`? `MongoDatabase#getCollection`? Or some time when I perform an action on the collection itself, such as .find?

What should be saved off?  Should I have multiple instances of the Database? the Collection?  or is it just the client?

Mainly I'm trying to make sure that I don't limit myself to one connection but that I also don't spam the database unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once instance should be fine per application. [MongoDB Driver Quick Tour - Java](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/#making-a-connection:b8bcd3c4cba9ac16433f82561ee44461) seems clear enough. EDIT: My understanding of the writing is that when you call `MongoClient.getDB();` is when you are connecting, to be sure parsing through their source code if available to see the exact moment. EDIT 2: Added links to MongoDB Java Driver which is here [MongoDB Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) and particularly the class your checking for is [MongoClient](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver/src/main/com/mongodb/MongoClient.java) which extends `Mongo.class` which is where the `.getDB();` is located; in this method they check the DB Cache and if not they create a new `DB.class` Instance. After running through the code it appears in the `Mongo.class` constructor so when you call `new MongoClient();` they call `connector.start()`

```
 public Mongo( ServerAddress addr , MongoOptions options )
        throws MongoException {
        _addr = addr;
        _addrs = null;
        _options = options;
        _applyMongoOptions();
        _connector = new DBTCPConnector( this , _addr );
        _connector.start();
        _cleaner = new DBCleanerThread();
        _cleaner.start();
    }
```

From their page

```
// To directly connect to a single MongoDB server (note that this will not auto-discover the primary even
// if it's a member of a replica set:
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
// or
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" );
// or
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
// or, to connect to a replica set, with auto-discovery of the primary, supply a seed list of members
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
                                      new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018),
                                      new ServerAddress("localhost", 27019)));

DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" );
```

> At this point, the db object will be a connection to a MongoDB server
>   for the specified database. With it, you can do further operations.
>
> The MongoClient class is designed to be thread safe and shared among
>   threads. Typically you create only 1 instance for a given database
>   cluster and use it across your application.
>
> important
>
> When creating many MongoClient instances:
>
> ```
> All resource usage limits (max connections, etc) apply per MongoClient instance
> To dispose of an instance, make sure you call MongoClient.close() to clean up resources
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If you could add some info about the default number of connections in the connection pool and when to close the connection or self-managed etc, then it would be very helpful!

Comment: @notionquest You are fully capably of doing the research as well. I simply looked everything up in their documentation or browsed the OPEN SOURCE code and read what was happening.